# How to add additional dll to Roslyn analyzer NuGet package?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, nuget, roslyn-code-analysis

**In short**: I referenced additional dll in my code-analyzer. All good with unit-tests & while I debugged analyzer by F5. But when this analyzer was installed as NuGet package to real project, it can't find that additional dll & crashes.

**#Optional reading - detailed version of question:**

I've wrote my code-analyzer (say `MyAnalyzer`). It finds some types forbidden to use in client code. And its codeFix replaces these types by allowed replacement-types from my custom dll (say `myCustom.dll`). I've added this dll as dependency to `MyAnalyzer.CodeFixes` project & to `MyAnalyzer.Test` unit tests project of analyzer solution.

And it works fine when started by F5 (at special opened VisualStudio instance) & successfully passes all unit tests.

But when I:

- built NuGet package of analyzer (by building `MyAnalyzer.Package` - a special project from VS template to produce analyzer NuGet packege)
- then coppied it to NuGet local feed (local path registered at NuGet manager as packages source)
- & then install this NuGet package from that local feed to real project by NuGet manager,

diagnostics rise fine, but when I try use codefix, which should replace some type by one from that `myCustom.dll`, my analyzer **can't find `myCustom.dll` & throws an exception**:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'myCustom, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I probably add reference to my dll at wrong way (not working with analyzers)? Or may be (its only my assumption) any dependency of NuGet package should be NuGet package too?

**#Additional info** (may be it matters):

Build output looks Ok: folder with build output contains that my referenced dll.

I copied it as is to NuGet local feed folder.

But cache folder of installed package, which appears after installing package, doesn't contain that `myCustom.dll`. It contains (except for a few small files) only:

`C:\Users\user1\.nuget\packages\myanalyzer\0.0.1\MyAnalyzer.0.0.1.nupkg`

& 2 dlls:

`C:\Users\user1\.nuget\packages\myanalyzer\0.0.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\MyAnalyzer.dll`
`C:\Users\user1\.nuget\packages\myanalyzer\0.0.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\MyAnalyzer.CodeFixes.dll`

And when I try to manually put my dll there - to package cahe folder, analyzer still throws exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And when I try to manually put my dll there - to package cahe folder,
> analyzer still throws exception.

That is not a right way. The issue describes that you have some wrong old version of the nuget under the global cache. Since you do not change the new release version to another, the old wrong nuget package is the same as the new release one, nuget package manager always install the version under the global cache first and if it does not find the same version of the nuget package by **nuget package manager UI**, it will then download the specific, different version from the nuget package feed into global cache `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\`, and then install it into your project.

You should try the following steps to make a careful check:

**1)** check your new packed nuget package `myanalyzer` under the local feed. And you can use `7zip` tool to unpack `myanalyzer.0.0.1.nupkg`.

Check whether the `myCustom.dll` is under the folder `myanalyzer.0.0.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\`.

**Also**, I found the error is

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MyCustomDll, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
```

I am curious why the dll is not right. And the error is that you have used `MyCustomDll.dll` rather than `MyCustom.dll`. You should check your **Analyzers** file and make sure that use the right named file.

**Then**, repack the new nuget project, ensure the new release nuget package is right.

**2)** delete the cache folder under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\myanalyzer`.

If you use `packages.config` nuget management format, and you should also delete the folder under your solution folder `<solution_folder>\packages\myanalyzer.0.0.1`.

**3)** after that, reinstall the right version under **package manager UI**.

**Update**

Sorry for that I ignored the pack steps of your analyzer nuget project.

**Actually**,  if the dlls are referenced by your current nuget project, the pack button has no duty to pack these dlls into the `nupkg` file automatically.

You have to pack it manually, no matter how you did, you have to modify the csproj file.

**Solution**

Use your target or another is to add these under `myanalyzer.package.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <None Include ="$(TargetDir)mycustom.dll" pack="true" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs"></None>
</ItemGroup>
```

**Then**, repack the project, clean the nuget caches, then install the new one.

> I wonder, why all dlls are present twice at installed NuGet package:
> as separate files at packages\myanalyzer\0.0.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs &
> as part of archive in .nupkg file. Or all content of installed package
> folder, except .nupkg file, is just unpacked .nupkg?

The `nupkg` is the file is the original version of your nuget package. It is generated by your pack nuget project.  And the folder which contains the nupkg is a local nuget feed.

[image]

The folder is like `nuget.org` source. And this folder which contains it is the nuget package source(nuget download nuget files from this path and then download the **nupkg** and unpack it under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`)

**Besides**, the `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages` is the [global nuget cache folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders).

[image]

**So** it restores the download nuget packages from the local feed, and if you installed the old same version of the myanalyzer nuget package before, it will always install the old same version like `1.0.0` from the cache folder no matter you have packed a new release same `1.0.0` version. Because the version is the same, so VS IDE will judge that there is already has a same nuget package under the cache folder, it always install the old one rather than the new one.

**So** that is why I recommended that you should delete all cache files under that folder. Avoid VS installing older cache packages all the time. Or you should set a new version for the updated nuget package like `2.0.0`.

**This** is the explanation and the difference between these two Folders.

**One** is the original local nuget package feed. Another is the storage path and unpacking path of the package downloaded from the local nuget package feed, and it will record the previously downloaded packages. You need to pay attention to this.

Comment: I'm sorry. The name of dll `MyCustomDll`, you noticed, is wrong. It should be `myCustom`, as you expected. I made this mistake, while changed real names in question. (I've fixed it in question)

Comment: Sara, I'm really grateful to you! Your guess turned out to be not true cause of problem, but thanks to the information you provided, I have found a solution to my problem, & probably the true cause of it.
I solve my problem by manually add `myCustom.dll` to the `<Target Name="_AddAnalyzersToOutput">` section of `MyAnalyzer.Package.csproj` by `<TfmSpecificPackageFile Include="$(OutputPath)\myCustom.dll" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" />` instruction.
I expected it should be done by setting `Copy Local` prop. of assembly in `.Package` project Dependencies without manual editing csproj

Comment: Writing "_Build output looks Ok: folder with build output contains that my referenced dll._" in question, I mean dll was present as separate file at buid output folder (namely at `MyAnalyzer.Package/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/`)
But when I unpacked `.nupkg` file, as you advised, it contained only 2 dlls: `MyAnalyzer.dl` & `MyAnalyzer.CodeFixes.dl`.

Comment: I wonder, why all dlls are present twice at installed NuGet package: as separate files at  `packages\myanalyzer\0.0.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs` & as part of archive in `.nupkg` file. Or all content of installed package folder, except `.nupkg` file, is just unpacked `.nupkg`?

Comment: I have updated my answer and you can check it,

Comment: Thank you! And, if you let, the last subquestion: Do you know, what does the `TfmSpecificPackageFile` from line `<TfmSpecificPackageFile Include="$(OutputPath)\MyAnalyzer.dll" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" />` from my `MyAnalyzer.Package.csproj` file mean. And what does the `None` from the line `<None Include ="$(TargetDir)mycustom.dll" pack="true" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs"></None>` you advised to add to `.csproj` file mean? Does the `Tfm` from `TfmSpecificPackageFile` stands for "Target FraMework"? (I can't find information about it)

Comment: I've found, what `Tfm` is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/target-frameworks#supported-frameworks